# GTK+ / C: Error : "gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed" when passing a structure to a function via "g_signal_connect"

Tags: c, user-interface, struct, callback, gtk

I am creating a calculator that, when finding "x" in a row, should ask for the value for "x". I am creating an additional window that contains "entry" and two buttons "Ok" and "Cancel".
When I pass a structure containing GtkWidget *entry and gchar *xValue[255] through the g_signal_connect key press handler, the following error occurs inside the function when accessing entry: "gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)'failed".

```
// My structs

typedef struct GlobalData
{
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkWidget *window;
} GlobalStruct;

typedef struct DialogData
{
    GtkWidget *dialogEntry;
    gchar xValue[255];
} DialogStruct;
```

```
gint main(gint argc, gchar **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GlobalStruct globalData;
    
    CreateWindow(&globalData);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void CreateWindow(GlobalStruct *globalData)
{
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *calcGrid;

    globalData->window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(globalData->window), "SmartCalc_v1.0");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(globalData->window), 500, 500);

    g_signal_connect(globalData->window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(OnWindowClosed), NULL);

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(globalData->window), 10);

    gchar *calcButton[] = {
        "atan", "^", "sqrt", "(", ")",
        "tan", "+", "-", "*", "/",
        "acos", "7", "8", "9", "mod",
        "asin", "4", "5", "6", "log",
        "cos", "1", "2", "3", "ln",
        "sin", "x", "0", ".", "="};

    calcGrid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(globalData->window), calcGrid);

    globalData->entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(calcGrid), globalData->entry, 0, 0, 5, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(globalData->entry, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(globalData->entry, TRUE);

    gint gridWidth = 5, gridHeight = 8, buttonIndex = 0;

    for (gint i = 1; i < gridHeight - 1; i++)
    {
        for (gint j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++)
        {
            button = gtk_button_new_with_label(calcButton[buttonIndex++]);
            gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(calcGrid), button, j, i, 1, 1);
            gtk_widget_set_hexpand(button, TRUE);
            gtk_widget_set_vexpand(button, TRUE);
            g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(ButtonClicked), globalData);
        }
    }

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Delete");
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(calcGrid), button, 0, gridHeight - 1, 5, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(button, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(button, TRUE);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(ButtonClicked), globalData);

    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(calcGrid), 10);
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(calcGrid), 10);

    gtk_widget_show_all(globalData->window);
}

void ButtonClicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    GlobalStruct *globalData = (GlobalStruct *)data;
    GtkEntry *entry = GTK_ENTRY(globalData->entry);

    const gchar *buttonLabel = gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(button));
    const gchar *currentText = gtk_entry_get_text(entry);

    if (!g_strcmp0(buttonLabel, "Delete"))
    {
        gtk_entry_set_text(entry, "");
    }
    else if (!g_strcmp0(buttonLabel, "="))
    {
        gchar answer[255] = {0};
        GetAnswer(currentText, answer, globalData);
        g_print("\nBefore inserting into entry\n");
        gtk_entry_set_text(entry, (const gchar *)answer);
        g_print("\nAfter inserting into entry\n");
        // g_free((gchar *)answer);
        g_print("\nAfter freeing the answer array\n");
    }
    else
    {
        gchar *newText = g_strdup_printf("%s%s", currentText, buttonLabel);
        gtk_entry_set_text(entry, newText);
        g_free(newText);
    }
}

void CreateDialogWindow(GlobalStruct *globalData, DialogStruct *dialogData)
{
    GtkWidget *dialogWindow;
    GtkWidget *dialogGrid;
    
    GtkWidget *cancelButton;
    GtkWidget *okButton;

    // Creating the dialog window
    dialogWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialogWindow), "Enter the value of x");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(dialogWindow), 300, 200);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dialogWindow), GTK_WINDOW(globalData->window));

    // Creating a grid for placing widgets
    dialogGrid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(dialogWindow), dialogGrid);

    // Creating an input widget (entry)
    dialogData->dialogEntry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(dialogGrid), dialogData->dialogEntry, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(dialogData->dialogEntry, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(dialogData->dialogEntry, TRUE);
    
    // Initializing the string in the DialogStruct structure
    g_strlcpy(dialogData->xValue, "", sizeof(dialogData->xValue));

    // Creating the "OK" button
    okButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("OK");
    g_signal_connect(okButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(OkButtonClicked), dialogData);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(dialogGrid), okButton, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(okButton, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(okButton, TRUE);

    // Creating the "Cancel" button
    cancelButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Cancel");
    g_signal_connect(cancelButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(OkButtonClicked), dialogData);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(dialogGrid), cancelButton, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(cancelButton, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(cancelButton, TRUE);

    // Setting the spacing between widgets in the grid
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(dialogGrid), 10);
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(dialogGrid), 10);

    // Showing all widgets of the dialog window
    gtk_widget_show_all(dialogWindow);
}

// Implementation of the function handling the "OK" button click
void OkButtonClicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    DialogStruct *dialogData = (DialogStruct *)data;

    const gchar *entryText = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(dialogData->dialogEntry));
    g_print("Entry Content: %s\n", entryText);

    // Additional processing of the entryText value can be done here
    // For example, convert it to a number and use it further.
}

void GetAnswer(const gchar *inputText, gchar *answer, GlobalStruct *globalData)
{
    Array inputArray;
    CreateArray(&inputArray);
    // Convert the expression string to a structure
    ConvertToArray(&inputArray, inputText);
    g_print("\nInfixArray:\n");
    PrintPolish(&inputArray);
    g_print("\n");
    gboolean xFlag = false; // Flag indicating the presence of "x" in the expression
    // Check the received expression for mathematical correctness
    if (CheckInfix(&inputArray, &xFlag))
    {
        if (xFlag)
        {
            // Find "x" in inputArray and replace it with the requested value
            g_print("\nFound \"x\"\n");
            DialogStruct dialogData;
            CreateDialogWindow(globalData, &dialogData);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing "g_signal_connect" to "g_signal_connect_swapped" and "g_signal_connect_data", no changes. I tried declaring the structure inside the "CreateDialogWindow" or "buttonClicked" function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `g_signal_connect` calls are passing a `GtkWidget` as first parameter, that's wrong, pass an object.

Switch from:

```
g_signal_connect(cancelButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(OkButtonClicked), dialogData);
```

to

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(cancelButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(OkButtonClicked), dialogData);
```

I don't see the 'key press handler' mentioned in the question (but you are probably making the same mistake in that case).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I have fixed the errors you indicated, but I still get an error when pressing the "ok" or "cancel" key. 
I also noticed that in the "OkButtonClicked" function, the address "dialogData->dialogEntry" is missing ("nil" is specified), however, in the "CreateDialogWindow" function, the address is displayed correctly.
What else could be the reason for this behavior of the program?

Comment: @Cheval-R I'm not sure because right now I can not test it, but I think the problem is that `gtk_widget_show_all(dialogWindow);` does not block or wait for an user action, so when you click on the ok or cancel button, the function `GetAnswer` is no longer running (thus the memory dedicated to `DialogStruct dialogData;` no longer exists at that point), try using dynamic memory instead of using a local variable, (or declare `static DialogStruct dialogData;` ... just to confirm this point)

Comment: Looks like you were right. I combined the two structures and got one structure containing the two previous ones.
However, maybe there is some more convenient solution?

Comment: I would use a modal dialog: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Dialog.run.html and keep the program as is (in this way `GetAnswer` doesn't go out of scope until you exit the form)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I replaced the creation of an additional window with the creation of a dialog.